# Problem While Deploying Application in GlassFish

Tags: java, glassfish

I have to deploy an application named "mrs-ws-server.war" in glassfish. I did it using both :

1) Package File to be uploaded to the server 
2) Local package File or Directory

at the address : http://localhost:42328/common/index.jsf

It generates the following error :

```
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
```

What should be the solution for the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a [number of possible root causes](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Unable+to+Start+due+to+GenericJDBCException+Cannot+open+Connection+Error).  Is there more information in the server log that might help someone help you?

Comment: The link 'number of possible root causes' is broken.